# Unable to train or test data

Tags: python, classification, svm, csv

I have this code as mentioned by this gentleman in "https://github.com/venky14/Machine-Learning-with-Iris-Dataset/blob/master/Machine%20Learning%20with%20Iris%20Dataset.ipynb"

After splitting the data into training and testing , I am unable to taking the features for training and testing data.Error is being thrown at In[92].

It is giving me 
error "KeyError: "['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'H' 'I'] not in index""

Below is image of how my CSV file looks like [image]

Comment: Show where exactly you are getting the error, it looks like you are accessing those columns with those keys, access it with an list of keys

Comment: You should post relevant part of your code here and preferably a sample of data also (e.g. using `df.head()`)

Comment: Thanks  a lot sir. Resolved it and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You should post here where was the problem and how did you solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are calling column names as indexes. 
Please provide sample code because the refed ipynb seems to be correct. 
Probably you are looking for this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample-table.csv')
df_selected_columns = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I']]
np_ndarray = df_selected_columns.values
```

Comment: Thank you so much for time sir. Resolved it. Sorry for the inconvenience